# TortoiseSVN checkout: file/folder order

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When TortoiseSVN checks out a working copy from a repository, in what order does it retrieve  the folders and files?

Comment: (If something is unclear, please comment and I'd love to clarify)

Comment: Can't find the information in the TSVN docs. But you can setup a repository with several large files (and setting up a folder structure) and check it out. By comparing the time-stamp of the files in the newly checkout working copy, you can make a good guess.

Comment: ask this in the TSVN forums: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewForumSummary.do?dsForumId=4061

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order in which data is received is not specified. You **must not** rely on that order because it can change.

And it will change - it's different between servers, it's even different between revisions of the repository. So **do not ever** rely on the order.

Comment: Thanks, so from the same repo server and assuming there have been no new revision the order is the same?

Comment: No, not necessarily. As I said: you must not rely on the order.